# how does $PATH$ being $NL$-complete help to prove $NL = coNL$

Tags: complexity-theory

There is a proof in Sipser showing that $NL = coNL$ (theorem 8.27 in the 3rd edition).

In the proof idea, the first sentence is: "We show that $\overline{PATH}$ is in $NL$, and thereby establish that every problem in $coNL$ is also in $NL$, because $PATH$ is $NL$-complete." I'm having trouble understanding this.

Sipser did not elaborate on this, but it sounds like the logic behind this sentence is:

1. $PATH$ is $NL$-complete
2. so $\overline{PATH}$ is $coNL$-hard
3. and $\overline{PATH}$ is in $NL$
4. so $coNL \subseteq NL$

If so, why can we get 2 from 1?

More generally, since $PATH$ can be *decided* in $NL$ (Sipser example 8.19), why can't we just flip the result to decide $\overline{PATH}$ directly?

Comment: The definition of coNL is: all problems whose complement is in NL.

Comment: You can't "flip the result" in nondeterministic models. For example, it is known that the r.e. languages are not closed under complement.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for the comments. 1. Are you saying we can reduce from $\overline{L}$ to $L$, then $L$ to $PATH$, then $PATH$ to $\overline{PATH}$? Or the fact that $L$ is reducible to $PATH$ means $\overline{L}$ is reducible to $\overline{PATH}$? 2. I understand why such behavior is incorrect for $NP$ and $coNP$, as there're certificates and verifiers involved, but I still can't see why it's the case here. Say there is no path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$, then a decider for $PATH$ will say no, and by reversing the output, the answer is valid for $\overline{PATH}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathsf{NL}$ consists of all languages accepted by nondeterministic Turing machines using logarithmic space. One way to think of such machines is as follows:

- The input is written on a read-only input tape.
- There are one or more work tapes of logarithmic size.
- There is a read-only oracle tape on which the head is constrained to only move to the right.

We can think of each such machine as computing a Boolean function on two arguments: $x$, which is the actual input, and $y$, which is the initial contents of the oracle tape. Such a machine $M$ nondeterministically computes the language $L(M)$ given by:
$$
x \in L(M) \Longleftrightarrow \exists y \text{ s.t. $M(x,y)$ accepts}.
$$
In other words, a language $L$ is in $\mathsf{NL}$ if there exists a logspace Turing machine $M$ with an auxiliary oracle input such that
$$
x \in L \Longleftrightarrow \exists y \text{ s.t. $M(x,y)$ accepts}.
$$

A language is in $\mathsf{coNL}$ if its complement is in $\mathsf{NL}$. Equivalently, a language $L$ is in $\mathsf{coNL}$ if there exists a logspace Turing machine $M$ with an auxiliary oracle input such that
$$
x \notin L \Longleftrightarrow \exists y \text{ s.t. $M(x,y)$ rejects}.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
x \in L \Longleftrightarrow \forall y \text{ $M(x,y)$ accepts}.
$$

Suppose now that $L$ is in $\mathsf{NL}$, say $L = L(M)$, and let $M'$ be obtained from $M$ by complementing the output. Then
$$
x \in L(M') \Longleftrightarrow \exists y \text{ s.t. $M'(x,y)$ accepts}
\Longleftrightarrow \exists y \text{ s.t. $M(x,y)$ rejects}.
$$
As you can see, $L(M')$ isn't necessarily the complement of $L(M)$. Indeed, given any machine $M$, we can come up with another machine $\tilde{M}$ such that $L(M) = L(\tilde{M})$, but $\tilde{M}(x,y_0)$ always rejects, for some fixed $y_0$ (for example, $\tilde{M}(x,0\Sigma^*)$ always rejects, and $\tilde{M}(x,1y) = M(x,y)$). In this case, $L(\tilde{M}') = \Sigma^*$.

---

Now I can answer your questions:

- $\overline{\mathsf{PATH}} \in \mathsf{coNL}$ since $\mathsf{PATH} \in \mathsf{NL}$ and *by definition* $\mathsf{coNL}$ consists of the complements of all languages in $\mathsf{NL}$.
- Furthermore, $\overline{\mathsf{PATH}}$ is $\mathsf{coNL}$-hard because $\mathsf{PATH}$ is $\mathsf{NL}$-hard. Indeed, suppose that $L \in \mathsf{coNL}$. Then $\overline{L} \in \mathsf{NL}$. Since $\mathsf{PATH}$ is $\mathsf{NL}$-hard, there is a logspace reduction $f$ such that $x \in \overline{L}$ iff $f(x) \in \mathsf{PATH}$. Thus $x \in L$ iff $f(x) \in \overline{\mathsf{PATH}}$, and so $f$ also reduces $L$ to $\overline{\mathsf{PATH}}$.
- Flipping the output value of a nondeterministic machine does not result in complementing the accepted language.

Elaborating on the second point, for some nondeterministic complexity classes $\mathsf{X}$, it is known that $\mathsf{X} \neq \mathsf{coX}$. The simplest example is $\mathsf{RE} \neq \mathsf{coRE}$: the halting problem is in $\mathsf{RE}$ but not in $\mathsf{coRE}$. Therefore $\mathsf{NL} = \mathsf{coNL}$ is a nontrivial statement.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand the second point now. Out of curiosity, if we don't have the oracle tape (as $NL$ is defined in Sipser), would it be much more difficult to prove this point? As for the first point, just to double check, you are saying $\overline{PATH}$ is $coNL$-hard because $PATH$ is $NL$-complete AND $\overline{PATH} \in coNL$?

Comment: It's hard for me to answer your first question, since I don't know which definition Sipser uses. But the definition is probably very similar, albeit it might look different.

Comment: For the second question, see my updated answer.

Comment: Sipser's definition of $NL$ is indeed similar. It has only one read-only input tape and one read-write work tape. I suppose arguing with this definition is non-trivial and my original question is solved now, but you can answer that question if you want : )